# How can I prevent FolderBrowserDialog to crash?

Tags: c#

When the FolderBrowserDialog appears, and I press the close button or cancel button, it shows an error message. What do I need to do?

Thank you.

Here's my code.

```
private void openSlideShowFolder_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    folderBrowserDialog1.ShowDialog();
    string[] pics1 = Directory.GetFiles(folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath, "*.jpg");
    string[] pics2 = Directory.GetFiles(folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath, "*.jpeg");
    string[] pics3 = Directory.GetFiles(folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath, "*.bmp");
    folderFile = new string[pics1.Length + pics2.Length + pics3.Length];
    Array.Copy(pics1, 0, folderFile, 0, pics1.Length);
    Array.Copy(pics2, 0, folderFile, pics1.Length, pics2.Length);
    Array.Copy(pics3, 0, folderFile, pics1.Length + pics2.Length, pics3.Length);
    selected = 0;
    showImage(folderFile[selected]);
}
```

Comment: You haven't catch SelectedPath when it's null. In this case SelectedPath is null and I'm sure you have assigned it for something

Comment: 1) Show us the code where you invoke the dialog, 2) Please copy and paste the text of the error message you are getting.

Comment: @hicurin: i don't think that is problem of OP, as OP says it crashed when clicked on close,cancel button.

Comment: http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/284917-why-does-creating-this-new-task-crash-my-program/

Comment: @Monika That has nothing to do with this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As was mentioned you need to catch whether the dialog returns OK.  See if this helps:

```
private void openSlideShowFolder_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(folderBrowserDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
    string[] pics1 = Directory.GetFiles(folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath, "*.jpg");
    string[] pics2 = Directory.GetFiles(folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath, "*.jpeg");
    string[] pics3 = Directory.GetFiles(folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath, "*.bmp");
    folderFile = new string[pics1.Length + pics2.Length + pics3.Length];
    Array.Copy(pics1, 0, folderFile, 0, pics1.Length);
    Array.Copy(pics2, 0, folderFile, pics1.Length, pics2.Length);
    Array.Copy(pics3, 0, folderFile, pics1.Length + pics2.Length, pics3.Length);
    selected = 0;
    showImage(folderFile[selected]);
    }
}
```

Comment: If you have the answer you need, please mark this answered.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation for [`ShowDialog`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e61ft40c%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) shows that it gives a result, telling you whether the user clicked OK. Your code is assuming the user always clicks OK, it's continuing regardless of the result. You need to check the return value, and only continue if it's `DialogResult.OK`.

If you do continue even though the user clicked Cancel or Close, several assumptions that should otherwise always be valid, may not hold. In particular, there is no path that the user has selected, because the user has not selected anything.